# How to CONCAT two columns then use the combined string in the WHERE clause in SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, db2

I have to search a DB2 database for a string that is a concatenation of two columns. Is there a way to CONCAT the columns then use the combined string in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more searching in the IBM manuals I came up with this solution that works for me;

```
Select
 Col1 || Col2 as MyCol1
Where CONCAT(RTRIM(Col1),(RTRIM(Col2)) = 'searchvalue'
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select * 
from MyTable
where Col1 concat Col2 = 'MySearchValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(column1, column2) AS s FROM table WHERE column3 = s
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution works, no need to use `CONCAT()`.

```
 SELECT Col1 || Col2 as MyCol1 
 FROM MY_TABLE
 WHERE Col1 || Col2 = 'searchvalue'
```

Just beware that the search will **not be indexed**. If you want it to be indexed, you have to use an index based on a function. Then 2 possibilities :

1. The DB engine supports it (I don't think that DB2 does)
2. Do it yourself : use an extra indexed column updated via triggers on INSERT & UPDATE.